# How can interrupt a sound that is playing on the iPhone (SDK or MonoTouch)?

Tags: iphone, audio, xamarin.ios

The sound is started using MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.SystemSound and I would like to stop the playback when I receive a specific event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop sounds playing with AudioToolbox.  You need to move to AVAudioPlayer or other framework in order to get that functionality.  AudioToolbox is for starting a quick sounds and letting it play through to end.  Sort of like an alert sound or sysbeep.